# Autocorrelation for an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

For an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process of the form

\begin{equation}
 dx=a(t)x(t)dt+N(t)dW,
\end{equation}

Suppose $y(t)=x(t+\Delta t)$.
I am trying to calculate $\mathbb{E}[xy]$ using Ito's lemma: $$d[xy]=dx*y+x*dy+dxdy.$$ So far, I have
$$d[xy]=a(t)xydt+N(t)ydW(t)+a(t+\Delta t) xy dt+N(t+\Delta t) x dW(t+\Delta t)+N(t)N(t+\Delta t) dt.$$

I am not sure how to proceed. I think that $\mathbb{E}[x(t) dW(t)]=0$, but what is $\mathbb{E}[x(t) dW(t+\Delta t)]$? What about $\mathbb{E} [x(t+\Delta t)dW(t)]$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure you did that right, but either way $x(t)dW(t) = x(t)N(t)dt$, so its expectation is likely not zero.

Comment: Would it make a difference if $\mathbb{E} [x]=0$?

Comment: Quite possibly. Do we know anything about $N(\cdot)$? Still not sure what to do with $W(t+\delta t)$.

Comment: $N(\cdot)$ is the time-varying periodic noise amplitude. $a(t)$ has the same period. $N(t)\geq0 \ \forall t$.

Comment: You can't apply Ito's lemma as $x(t+\Delta t)$ is not known at $t$, it is not "adapted". Try to modify the solution approach for the covariance here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process.